# How can I iterate thru all controls from a View on iOS?

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4

I want to iterate thru all controls existing in a View on iOS when the view is loaded.

Also, it would be acceptable to have a callback that is called when these controls are initialized.

How can I obtain this?

Comment: Immediate children or is it a view hierarchy with two or more levels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To iterate through subviews (controls) in a parent view, call the parent view's `-subviews` method:

```
for (UIView *subview in [parentView subviews]) {
    /* do something with subview */
}
```

You could subclass the control, creating a custom control. Here, you override the custom control view's initializer method. In this method, you would call the parent's initializer, and add your custom code.

Answer (score 0):

`for (UIView *aView in [myView subviews]) { //do something with aView }`?